# I'm so stucked in this method problems

Tags: javascript, class, object, methods

This class creates credits packages after I have a method to see these packages in DOM across a form, but I need to create a method to destroy that content through a button on the form, and I'm not succeeding.
Any help you give me, even if it is not a total resolution, but a guide to solving this I would appreciate it.

```
class Paquete {
    constructor(montoCredito, plazosCredito, cuotaTotal, tasasCredito) {
        this.monto = parseFloat(montoCredito);
        this.plazos = plazosCredito;
        this.cuota = parseFloat(cuotaTotal);
        this.tasas = tasasCredito;
    }
    
    mostrar() {
        let cuadros = document.createElement("article")
        cuadros.innerHTML = `<h3>Paquete Crediticio</h3>
                            <p>Prestamo de hasta: ${this.monto} pesos</p>
                            <p>Que puede ser devuelto en: ${this.plazos}</p>
                            <p>Con tasas del: ${this.tasas}</p>
                            <p>Con una cuota de: ${this.cuota} pesos</p>
                            <p>El valor mostrado como cuota es referencial al monto maximo mostrado</p>
                            <button> Me interesa!</button>`                                                 
        document.getElementById("prestamos").appendChild(cuadros)
    
    }
    mostrarDisculpa() {
        let disculpa = document.createElement("span");
        disculpa.innerHTML = `<h3>Disculpanos</h3>
                              <p>En este momento no tenemos una propuesta para vos</p>`;                    
        document.getElementById("prestamos").appendChild(disculpa);
        
    }
    eliminarContenido(){
     let prestamos = document.getElementById("prestamos")
     let removeContenido = span.removeChild(this.disculpa);
    }
}

const paquetesCreditos = [];
paquetesCreditos.push(
    new Paquete(200000, "12 meses", ((200000 * 1.48) / 12).toFixed(2), "48%")
);
paquetesCreditos.push(
    new Paquete(300000, "12 meses", ((300000 * 1.48) / 12).toFixed(2), "48%")
);
paquetesCreditos.push(
    new Paquete(400000, "12 meses", ((400000 * 1.48) / 12).toFixed(2), "48%")
);
paquetesCreditos.push(
    new Paquete(200000, "24 meses", ((200000 * 1.53) / 24).toFixed(2), "53%")
);
paquetesCreditos.push(
    new Paquete(300000, "24 meses", ((300000 * 1.53) / 24).toFixed(2), "53%")
);
paquetesCreditos.push(
    new Paquete(400000, "24 meses", ((400000 * 1.53) / 24).toFixed(2), "53%")
);
paquetesCreditos.push(
    new Paquete()
)

let formulario = document.getElementById("formSimulador");
let nombre = document.getElementById("campoNombre");
let apellido = document.getElementById("campoApellido");
let email = document.getElementById("campoEmail");
let salario = document.getElementById("campoSueldo");
let error = document.getElementById("error")
let buttonReset = document.getElementById("btn-delete")

formulario.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(salario.value)
  if (salario.value >= 20000 && salario.value <= 35000) {
    paquetesCreditos[0].mostrar();
    paquetesCreditos[3].mostrar();
  } else if (
    salario.value >= 35001 &&
    salario.value <= 50000
  ) {
    paquetesCreditos[1].mostrar();
    paquetesCreditos[4].mostrar();
  } else if (
    salario.value >= 60001 &&
    salario.value <= 400000
  ) {
    paquetesCreditos[2].mostrar();
    paquetesCreditos[5].mostrar();
  }
  else if (salario.value>=0 && salario.value <=19999){
      paquetesCreditos[6].mostrarDisculpa()
  }
  formulario.reset()
});

buttonReset.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(e)
    paquetesCreditos[0].eliminarContenido();
    paquetesCreditos[1].eliminarContenido();
    paquetesCreditos[2].eliminarContenido();
    paquetesCreditos[3].eliminarContenido();
    paquetesCreditos[4].eliminarContenido();
    paquetesCreditos[5].eliminarContenido();
    paquetesCreditos[6].eliminarContenido();
})
```

Comment: Please be specific about the problem you're having. What in particular is not succeeding?

Comment: now i edit the post !

Comment: Neither span in eliminarContenido nor this.disculpa exists.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: `mostrarDisculpa()` needs to do `this.disculpa = disculpa`. And `span.removeChild` should be `prestamos.removeChild`

Comment: You can also just do `this.disculpa.remove()`, you don't need to specify the parent.

Comment: add an id to the article then you can get it

Comment: I tried creating a function outside the method something like this 

function eliminarCuadros(){
 let cuadroCreado = document.getElementById("prestamos");
 document.getElementById("prestamos").remove(cuadroCreado)
}

but this delete the div "prestamos"

Comment: To clarify the picture, show () and showExcuse () are methods of the Package class, which both create a card in the DOM, displaying a message, now I need a method that can delete both, and I'm not able to.